# Android calendar library

Tags: android, caldroid

I'm looking for a calendar library to use in my android app. I am currently using Caldroid, but I find it to be very slow. Any suggestions on a calendar that loads quicker?

Comment: Try your luck with https://github.com/square/android-times-square.

Comment: i like the calendar, very quick. only issue - do you know how to implement the onitemselectedlistener to use the clicked date in a dialog?

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker .Try this its very quick and responsive .Plus it has got the material design view. You can customize the colors according to your theme.

Comment: can it be used in a layout, rather than as a popup?

Comment: No I'm afraid, It can be only used as a popup, for including in layout through xml you can try https://github.com/traex/CalendarListview